# Spirograph curves without gears, pen point

Tags: pstricks

I am using the `pst-spirograph` package. An image produced by this package will show the spirograph curve, but will also show the gears and the pen point. I would like to obtain just the curve. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-spirograph}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6.2,-6.2)(6.2,6.2)    
\psSpirograph[Z1=105,
              Z2=56,
              m=0.1,
              ap=10,
              holenumber=1,
              polarangle=0,
              thetamax=2880,
              color1=white,
              color2=white,
              linecolor=red,
              curvecolor=black]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces a drawing of the curve together with the gears that produce the curve:
[image: Curve with gears]

If I change `linecolor` to `white`, the gears will no longer show, but the inner gear is printed in white over the curve, producing breaks in the curve. Also, the pen point is still showing.
[image: Curve without gears but with breaks]

How can I eliminate the breaks and the pen point?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Nice first question, and big thanks for adding an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code modifies `\psSpirograph`'s internals to remove the inner and outer gears from the PostScript code entirely, leaving only the inner cycloid:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-spirograph,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\psSpirograph@ii}{Roue2}{}{}{}% Remove Roue2
\patchcmd{\psSpirograph@ii}{Roue1}{
  /Roue {} def % Overwrite definition of /Roue
  /COURONNE {} def % Overwrite definition of /COURONNE
  Roue1
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6.2,-6.2)(6.2,6.2)   
  \psSpirograph[Z1=105,
                Z2=56,
                m=0.1,
                ap=10,
                holenumber=1,
                polarangle=0,
                thetamax=2880,
                color1=white,
                color2=white,
                linecolor=red,
                curvecolor=black]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```